# Logging the output of a cmd window which is opened by another window

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to log the outputs from a cmd window. I am running a bat file which is producing some outputs and I want to log them.

For example I am running the 'test.bat' file from cmd. This opens another cmd window and the output is displayed over there. I want to log the output of the second window.

If I write test.bat > result.log it only logs the terminating message from the 1st cmd window.

Any help or hint will be much appreciated.

These are the contents of the batch file (say test.bat) that I am trying to run from cmd

```
start CPU.bat
timeout /t 10
taskkill /IM api_test.exe /F
```

The contents of CPU.bat are

```
.\api_test.exe cpu -m "name_of_some_model_to_be_tested"
```

Comment: So the other command starts a new window and releases control from the current window .... but why? you should `call` a batch file and not `start` one. How about showing the batch code?

Comment: Hi, 

here are the contents of the batch file (say 'test.bat') that I am executing from cmd

"CPU.bat timeout /t 10 taskkill /IM api_test.exe /F"

Now, if I just run this, the taskkill doesn't seem to work. 
Adding a 'start' before the CPU.bat kills api_test but it creates a new cmd window whose outputs I want to capture. I hope I could make it clear.

Comment: If I use call instead of start the taskkill doesn't kill api_test.exe. 

I have edited the question with the codeblock. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: if you are forced to use start, then maybe just do `start /b CPU.bat`

Comment: But it's not saving the outputs into the log file. 

This is what I am getting as outputs of the log file:
....
...
SUCCESS: The process "api_test.exe" with PID 21144 has been terminated.

Comment: So I guess then you wanted the output of `api_test.exe` to the logfile?

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is using as first command line:

```
start "CPU" %ComSpec% /C ""%~dp0CPU.bat" >"%UserProfile%\Desktop\CPU_Output.log" 2>&1"
```

This command line starts one more Windows command process with option `/C` to close this command process after execution of the specified command line finished. The console window opened gets the title `CPU`.

The started Windows command process executes the batch file `CPU.bat` which is in directory of the batch file containing this command line with full qualified file name. `%~dp0` expands to full path of currently executed batch file always ending with a backslash and therefore concatenated with just `CPU.bat` to full qualified file name of this batch file.

The standard output of `CPU.bat` is redirected into the file `CPU_Output.log` in desktop directory of current user. The error output is redirected into the same file.

Please read the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `>` and `2>&1`.

Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, run `start /?` and read the output help about this command. Next run `cmd /?` and read again the output help, especially the section about how the command line specified after option `/C` or `/K` is interpreted by Windows command processor which is very important here.

But `CPU.bat` is not needed at all on using this command line as first command line:

```
start "CPU" %ComSpec% /C ""%~dp0api_test.exe" cpu -m "name_of_some_model_to_be_tested" >"%UserProfile%\Desktop\CPU_Output.log" 2>&1"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this so detailed answer. One issue is here that the api_test.exe doesn't stop and run forever. I wanted to use the timeout option to kill this after a certain period of time which I am not being able to do. Is there any way to adopt this along with your provided solution? 

Thanks again for the answer. I really appreciate your effort.

Comment: My answer is just about the first command line which your question is about. The other two command lines in your batch file better written as `%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 10` and `%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /IM api_test.exe /F` (full names) must be also in your batch file to __kill__ `api_test.exe` after 10 seconds. I suggest to try first `taskkill.exe` without option `/F` which sends the message to this executable to __terminate__ itself. If that works and `api_test.exe` really terminates itself, it would be better than a forced __kill__ of this executable by Windows.